# Can't create ListView of RelativeLayouts for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

What I'm trying to accomplish is have a scrollable ListView that contains a RelativeLayout for each item. Each RelativeLayout contains a CheckBox and an EditText. My ArrayAdapter for the ListView contains the RelativeLayout type. When I create this ListView, each item is shown as the toString() of the layout instead of the layout itself. What should I be doing to accomplish this?

Comment: I know it's highly confidential, but we'll need to see the code. Probably the `Adapter` code

Answer (score 1):

**Init your list view**

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
```

**Create the adapter layout for your listview like  this (customview.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</<RelativeLayout >
```

**Create the AdapterClass and extend BaseAdapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


@Override
    public int getCount() {
            ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return ....;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            View row;

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customview, parent, false);

            TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            CheckBOx check = (CheckBOx) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            EditText edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            name.setText("Name");
            edit.setText("Address");

            return row;
        }
```

**Finally set the adapter to your ListView**

```
listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(contacts) );
```

Comment: This just about covers everything you need for listviews. Does it solve the issue?

Comment: I've run into some trouble with this, though maybe I don't fully understand adapters. How would I add an item using this CustomAdapter, assuming I've created one and set the view's adapter to it?

Answer (score 0):

Make your own subclass of `ArrayAdapter` and construct your RelativeLayout in [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

The type you set the ArrayAdapter to is for populating the content not constructing the view. To use a non-standard view like you want to do, you'll have to override BaseAdapter

You can see an example here:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown